# Read ACROSS MULTIPLE DISCIPLINES (phrasing)

Tags: sentence-construction, phrases

Let's say you wanted to learn from different sources from different authors. That's why you read books. You say:

> **sentence** # 1) I read books to learn and improve my English. I read across multiple disciplines.

[image]

Or

> **sentence** # 2) I read books to learn and improve my English. I read across **from** multiple disciplines. (My construction)

So are they different with each other? I can't find their difference, help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of these sentences are fine:

> I read **across** multiple disciplines.
>   I read **from** multiple disciplines.

---

However, you can't use [**across from**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/across%20from) because it's a set phrase that has a specific meaning:

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> : on the opposite side from (someone or something)
>   // She sat (directly) *across from* me at the table.
>   // The restaurant is (just) *across from* the high school.

Look at it in your sentence again:

> ✘ I read **across from** multiple disciplines.

What this is saying is that somebody or something called *multiple disciplines* is located on the other side of something that separates the two of you while you read.

---

Note that *across* and *from* can have subtly different meanings in your case.

When you use *across* you can imply a spectrum of reading material that extends from one discipline to another and which touches on all of the disciplines that could be considered in between the two.

For example, you could be reading material on art, art history, and history. (Where art history acts as a kind of bridge between the other two.)

---

When you use *from* you can simply be talking about multiple subjects, which may or may not have any relationship to each other.

For example, you read material on art and history—without there being anything that links them together.